# how many dynamic features are there in QT(Not in QML)?

Tags: c++, qt

We know that Qt has a plugin architecture that makes it possible to load code into an application without recompiling or relinking.

We also can integrate javascript into Qt using QScriptEngine.

I am wondering if there are any other dynamic features in Qt, which can add new features/functions to our application, without recompling or relinking.

Comment: Look at QML: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe too many (that's why your post is downvoted)

For example, you can get a python shell in your code without changing almost anything via the [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/) library

You can get [Lua](http://www.nongnu.org/libqtlua/) too!